# Microsoft WebMatrix: what is it?

Tags: asp.net

I'm a little confused about new Microsoft products. 
I'm a classic `webform Asp.Net` developer. I know exists also `Asp.Net MVC` with a different approach based on Mvc pattern. 
Now, i know exists also `WebMatrix` that uses new `Razor` "notation".

Can someone explain me what are the main difference between that "technology" ? When use WebMatrix, when WebForm ?
Thanks!

Comment: You may want to read http://blog.wekeroad.com/microsoft/someone-hit-their-head and http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Webmatrix is a platform that integrates a variety of recently released technologies such as IIS Express, Asp.Net Webforms, Razor, SQL Express etc. I guess from what I have been reading it's a way that eases the barrier to entry, for non-MS developers, into the MS world. In addition you can also use code your site in PHP and use a variety of open source tools for developing web sites. To directly answer your question, in you planning on creating a complex web application, WebMatrix may not be the solution you're looking for.

As a reference, I suggest reading through Scott Gu's [Introduction to Webmatrix](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/06/introducing-webmatrix.aspx)

> *WebMatrix will be able to take
>   advantage of these technologies to
>   facilitate a **simplified web
>   development workload that is useful
>   beyond professional development
>   scenarios** – and which enables even
>   more developers to be able to learn
>   and take advantage of ASP.NET for a
>   wider variety of scenarios on the web.*
>
> *If you are a professional developer
>   who has spent years with .NET you will
>   likely look at the below steps and
>   think – this scenario is so basic -
>   you need to understand so much more
>   than just this to build a “real”
>   application. What about encapsulated
>   business logic, data access layers,
>   ORMs, etc?  Well, if you are building
>   a critical business application that
>   you want to be maintainable for years
>   then you do need to understand and
>   think about these scenarios.
>   Imagine, though, that you are trying
>   to teach a friend or one of your
>   children how to build their first
>   simple application – and they are new
>   to programming.  Variables,
>   if-statements, loops, and plain old
>   HTML are still concepts they are
>   likely grappling with. Classes and
>   objects are concepts they haven’t even
>   heard of yet. Helping them get a
>   scenario like below up and running
>   quickly (without requiring them to
>   master lots of new concepts and steps)
>   will make it much more likely that
>   they’ll be successful – and hopefully
>   cause them to want to continue to
>   learn more.
>   **One of the things we are trying to-do
>   with WebMatrix is reach an audience
>   who might eventually be able to be
>   advanced VS/.NET developers – but who
>   find the first learning step today too
>   daunting, and who struggle to get
>   started.***

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still interested: a pretty good lessons here http://habrahabr.ru/company/microsoft/blog/136004/ . This link is for those, who understand russian.
Shortly speaking WebMatrix allows you to conveniently mix up C# server code and html (this mixing is provided by simple Razor sytax). Also in WbeMatrix 2.0(beta version now) is provided full IntelliSense for html/css/c# code.